# How to batch execute PHP scripts from one PHP script?

Tags: php, batch-file, scripting

I have a series of PHP scripts that I want to run in a particular order.  I tried using

```
<?php
    exec('file1.php');
    exec('file2.php');
    exec('file3.php');
?>
```

to accomplish this, but just got a series of errors.  If I run them from the command line, they all work fine. How to fix this problem?

Comment: What errors did you get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run it from the command line from your scripts, assuming you have root access.

Example:

```
<?php
    system("php -f path/to/your/script/file1.php");
    system("php -f path/to/your/script/file2.php");
    system("php -f path/to/your/script/file3.php");
?>
```

I haven't tested it, but it should work :)

Answer (score 2):

If the state of each script is well isolated (i.e. not clashing function/class names and global variables), you can just include each of them in turn.

```
include("file1.php");
include("file2.php");
...
```

This will also ensure you don't spin up multiple PHP interpreters.

Comment: Even better, make a function that includes the files. To prevent variables from being reset. This method of course has the disadvantage that if one script dies, so does the rest

Answer (score 0):

#### `system('php file1.php')`

Or, just use a shell script if on *nix.